# Efficient way to get the indizes of the k highest values in vector<float>

Tags: c++, time-complexity

How can I create a `std::map<int, float>` from a `vector<float>`, so that the map contains the k highest values from the vector with the keys beeing the index of the value in the vector.

A naive approach would be to traverse the vector (O(n)), extract and erase (O(n)) the highest element k times (O(k)), leading to a complexity of O(k*n^2), which is suboptimal, I guess.

Even better would be to just copy (O(n)) and remove the smallest until size is k. Which would lead to O(n^2). Still polynomial...

Any ideas?

Comment: copy to vector<pair<float,int>> then partial_sort that on the float?

Comment: `std::partial_sort` may help

Comment: std::partial_sort need random access iterators. If I understood correctly, map has "only" bidirectional ones.

Comment: I was more thinking of using an intermediate vector as the sort container. The copy is still an o(n). All this assuming the order is dominant over the unitary processing time.

Comment: In fact `std::nth_element` is better for OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should do the job:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

// Compare: greater T2 first.
struct greater_by_second
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator () (const std::pair<T1, T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1, T2>& rhs)
    {
        return std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first) > std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);
    }
};


std::map<std::size_t, float> get_index_pairs(const std::vector<float>& v, int k)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, float>> indexed_floats;

    indexed_floats.reserve(v.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = v.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        indexed_floats.emplace_back(i, v[i]);
    }
    std::nth_element(indexed_floats.begin(),
                     indexed_floats.begin() + k,
                     indexed_floats.end(), greater_by_second());
    return std::map<std::size_t, float>(indexed_floats.begin(), indexed_floats.begin() + k);
}
```

Let's test it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<float> fs {45.67f, 12.34f, 67.8f, 4.2f, 123.4f};

    for (const auto& elem : get_index_pairs(fs, 2)) {
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 67.8
4 123.4
```

Comment: Thats a bunch of code for an intuitionally felt simple thing. BUT if I understood the code correct it is a linear copy +  lineartithmic partial sort + linear remap, hence in O(n+k*logn). Great!

Comment: I changed `std::partial_sort` by `std::nth_element` as the order is useless (and lost in the map anyway). So the complexity is : Linear in the size of vector on average, so O(n).

Comment: The complexity does not change if you replace partial_sort by nth_element in this. It's O(n+k*log(k)) for both. Just the constants are a bit better for nth_element.

Comment: @ltjax: According to [nth-element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), **Complexity**: Linear in `std::distance(first, last)` on average.

Comment: @Jarod42: I know, but you are still inserting k elements into a map, which is O(k*log(k)). With partial sort you are just sorting the k elements twice under different criteria. Maybe I should have said "for the version with nth_element".

Comment: @ltjax: I miss the map insertion... so `partial_sort` : `O(n + n*log(k) + k*log(k))` versus `nth_element` : `O(n + ~n + k*log(k))`

Comment: The first bound is still a bit loose. Partial sort is also in ``O(n+k*log(k))`` - think nth_element+sort. Really just the k*log(k) term appears twice with partial sorting, but that does not matter with Big-Oh.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a list of the k-highest values so far, and update it for each of the values in your vector, which takes you down to O(n*log k) (assuming log k for each update of the list of highest values) or, for a naive list, O(kn).

You can probably get closer to O(n), but assuming k is probably pretty small, may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I get the vector as a bunch and cant "track" it. I had to compute the list of the k-highest values explicitly, which would still be in O(n^2).

Comment: @ManualSchneid3r: If you have no means of extracting the values from the vector, how do you compute the highest?  What access do you have to the contents of the vector?  (You might have listed such limitations in your original question...)

Comment: Check if the current element is greater than the current min. This may result in a speed-up depending on the distribution of values in the original data set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not get it, but in case the incremental approach is not an option, why not use  <s>`std::sort`</s> `std::partial_sort`?

That should be an o(n log k), and since k is very likely to be small, that makes practically an o(n).

Edit: thanks to Mike Seymour for the update.
Edit (bis):

The idea is to use an intermediate vector  for sorting, and then put it into the map. Trying to reduce the order of the computation would only be justified for significant amount of data, so I guess the copy time (in o(n) ) could be lost in background noise.

Edit (bis):

That's actually what the selected answer does, without the theorietical explanations :).

Comment: Or better still, `std::partial_sort` should be O(n log k).

Comment: Is `std::partial_sort` applicable to `map` at all? As mentioned it seems like `std::partial_sort` needs random-access iterators, which a `map` does not offer.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: `map` is already sorted. You'd use `partial_sort` on the vector, to find the entries you want to put into the map.

Comment: @MikeSeymour just because I like to be pedantic sometimes: `map` is ordered not sorted. There are ordered and unordered data structure in C++ standard library, not sorted ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your optimal solution will have a complexity of **O(n+k*log(k))**, since sorting the k elements can be reduced to this, and you will have to look at each of the elements at least once.

Two possible solutions come to mind:

1. Iterate through the vector while adding all elements to a bounded (size k) priority-queue/heap, also keeping their indices.
2. Create a copy of your vector with including the original indices, i.e. `std::vector<std::pair<float, std::size_t>>` and use `std::nth_element` to move the k highest values to the front using a comparator that compares only the first element. Then insert those elements into your target map. Ironically, that last step adds you the k*log(k) in the overall complexity, while nth_element is linear (but will permute your indices).

Comment: Ad point 1) optimize with a condition on the current min of the size k data structure. If the values in the original vector are uniformly distributed, this will probably result in a speed-up due to branch prediction after some steps.

Comment: Only if k<<n, but I guess we can safely assume that here. But in that case it's probably even faster to use a sorted array + insertion instead of a heap for the data-locality and branch-prediction features. Anyways, the question was tagged with complexity, so I guess that was more important than real world performance.